# PostgreSQL not starting correctly, is it repairing itself first?

Tags: postgresql

I never saw that problem before. I had problems and many PostgreSQL processes were stuck so I killed them with a -KILL...

When I tried to restart, it says that it cannot restart, but the daemon continues to run and uses a little processor a lot of I/O. Is it trying to repair the database?

I get no log at all. I think there is a way to increase log output... I'll look into that. At this point, the socket to connect to the server doesn't get created, but the server does not quit or emit any error/message, so I have no clue what is going on!?

If anyone has a clue, I'd be glad to hear about it.

Answer (score 6):

> I had problems and many postgresql processes were stuck so I killed them with a -KILL...

**Don't do this**. It won't cause data corruption, but as you've discovered it forces the whole database system to restart and do crash recovery.

If you hard-kill any database back-end with `SIGKILL` (`kill -9`) the postmaster has to assume that shared memory might be corrupted and it has to kill and restart all workers, doing crash recovery as if the server its self had crashed and restarted.

You should not need to `SIGKILL` a backend. Use regular `SIGTERM` to ask it to stop what it's doing and exit - or better, use `pg_terminate_backend(...)` from within SQL. If the back-end doesn't respond, `SIGQUIT` should force it to terminate.

If you do `SIGKILL`, crash recovery usually takes a few seconds; minutes for a really big and busy databases. However, if you have a long `checkpoint_timeout` and huge `checkpoint_segments` you can accumulate a *lot* of work that must be done before the DB can become available again. If you have quite slow disk I/O this will be even worse.

PostgreSQL *does* produce logs while it's in recovery, and they're at a log level that makes it unlikely that they'd be suppressed. So it's hard to say what could be going on. Maybe you were looking at syslog, but your PostgreSQL install is configured to log directly to files in `/var/log/pgsql` or in the `pg_log` directory in the datadir?

(For anyone else reading this, *never* `SIGKILL` the postmaster then delete the postmaster pid file and restart PostgreSQL while there are still old `postgres` back-ends running. That *can* cause data corruption, since you've disabled every safety measure PostgreSQL puts in place to stop you from starting a new postmaster while old backends might still be running.)

Comment: Hi Craig, I did use the normal `service postgresql stop` command in Ubuntu. That, by itself, took some 2 or 3 minutes. Then I looked at the processes and many Postgres backends were still running. When I tried to restart Postgres, it did not want to, with some errors... So I kill those left overs by hand. From what I could tell, they were completely stuck. Also when I restarted, the recovery took forever and the I/O generated a load average of about 10. Once the recovery was done, it took a little time, but the loadavg returned to 0.3 to 0.5 as usual!

Comment: By the way, I checked other logs, just in case, but the first one I looked at was `/var/log/postgresql/` which is the normal Ubuntu location. There were the files with some info, but only up to the point where I ran the `service postgresql stop`. Then nothing until the database finally restarted...

Comment: @AlexisWilke OK. In future, you should use `pg_ctl -m immediate stop` if your usual stop doesn't work. As for the logging details, maybe you've set `log_min_messages` to something really high, like `panic` ? It all sounds very odd. If I were looking into this I would probably be attaching `gdb` to one of the problem processes, trying to see what it was doing.

Comment: It looks like it is set to warning, (the default, right?) `#log_min_messages = warning`, as it is commented out. Are you saying that the postmaster may actually cleanly quit before all the backend processes are done? I think those processes were stuck, but I did not think to debug them... I wanted the websites to come back to life!

Comment: @AlexisWilke It's really hard to say what happened based only on this information; all I'm saying is what I'd do if I were in your position and trying to disagnose the fault. When PostgreSQL is doing recovery it'll log that fact, and your log level seems normal, so something quite anomalous seems to have been going on. Figuring out what in the absence of logging info would require capturing more information at the time.

Answer (score 2):

I did the same thing once (killing a postgres process), and the same thing happened. I knew it was very wrong to kill these processes forcibly, but I had to since the process had locked the DB for a long time and wouldn't quit. I'm just glad Postgres recovered all data on the next start.

Postgres does the right thing in this scenario; It rejects all new connections, and rolls back all running transactions and plays back the journals to make sure data files are consistent.

I don't know what you want Postgres to log for you, since you've killed a DB process, which you are not supposed to. You just need to sit and wait till it recovers.

Comment: Craig says that Postgres is expected to send some logs while recovering. I could not see anything until the recovery was over. I would think that even a simple message saying "Database not stopped cleaning, start recovering process" would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Well... the database finally started, it took something like 20 minutes (a long time to be down!), so I'm pretty sure it was repairing itself before restarting the whole database system.

I could see debug flowing once the restart process was done. Too bad that they do not post any logs about the fact. I still run 8.4 so maybe this is fixed in 9.x...

Comment: 8.4 is EOL !! You better upgrade. Check [Versioning policy](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Comment: I'm on 9.x since 2013... Thanks for the info.